# How to Import the Contents / Data in a Text file with One field using Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, pentaho-cde, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to Parse the data which is Present In an Unstructured Text File.
but Before that, I want the entire contents in that text file to store it into One field. So that, I can be able to parse the Data by Retrieving from the field.

I am Planning to Use **Javascript Modified Values** for parsing.

Note:
The file which I am Talking about is not a Normal Text or CSV File. It is a direct file which is received from **Tandem Server**.
eg:  (The contents in the text file)
'*|08-Jul-16|1|
5996|W2266001|BODHAN ROADNIZAMABAD|FNFA|5211080013438979|*****************|0220|01|7|07-Jul-16|08-Jul-16|23:14:23|1043|000|00|541100|30000|0000|PRO1|FNFA|00000403362|356|356|0|NIZ-220|NIZAMABAD|TS|IN||08-Jul-16|1|*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Load file content in memory" step for that.

It does exactly what you want, read file(s) into a single field per file without parsing. Rather than specifying a delimiter, you manually enter the field data.
Choose "file content" as the element and "string" as the type.

I have seen your other question. If your file is 1.7 GB in size, it will probably not load into a single row without memory issues.

I tested using:

[image: transformation steps to split unstructured file]

1. Load file to memory, as described above
2. Split field to rows, using "\|DR\|" as a regex delimiter
3. Select values, to get rid of the original huge field
4. Split fields,  using delimiter "|" into a list of string fields (as many as your records can have at most).

This gives somewhat usable records, but you may have to do more processing to identify missing columns in some records and straighten them out.

Comment: Since the file has No header and Footer, Its is not displaying the contents.

Comment: You can manually define the field in the fields tab, set the element to "file contents" and the type to string.

Comment: Could you please check once again? I have changed the file contents to string and file size to int. I couldn't find any option to set the field **Manually**. to your notice, when i try to view contents using  'preview rows', no rows found to be previewed is displaying.

Comment: Strange. I pasted your sample to a file and tried, it works. Are you trying with the full data file or one containing only a few lines? Btw, do you have any way at all of finding the start or end of a record?

Comment: I am trying with the file containing few lines. yes, it do have start and end. it can be separated by '|DR'. which can be used to find start and end of the record.

Comment: I have Loaded the contents in a text file as you have said. Text file Input -----------> Load File Content in memory. how can I view whether the data has been loaded properly? when I click on Preview, It is not showing anything. except empty field name. 'file content and file size'.

Comment: Don't use the text file input, the Load File step is the first step. THat's where you specifiy the files to read

Comment: Good solution. Its working properly. But don't we need RegEx as you have mentioned in the statement?

Comment: In Split Field to Rows, there's a checkbox to treat the delimiter as a regex, thought it might even work without if the step accepts "|DR|" as a delimiter.